# FILTER Range with Multiple Conditions - Skip Blank Cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, vlookup, multi-index, is-empty

Building a dynamic schedule dashboard in Google Sheets.

- Limited to using only functions and formulas, no scripts.
- Have a living table (range A1:M) where each row represents a different event.
- I need to pull multiple rows of data (all text strings) and populate into single column.
- Some columns may be empty (ie. not all events have an Agenda or a Group associated with them).
- Query and some other functions don't work because they won't pull the hyperlinks.

The below function works, but I cannot figure out how to get it to skip the blank cells.

=FLATTEN(FILTER($F$2:$M, $B$2:$B=$O$2, $D$2:$D=$Q$2, $E$2:$E=$P$2))

It would be great to add a blank column at the end though that is NOT skipped, so when it returns each row of event details into a column, there is a space between each event.

Here is an example of the table:

| Calendar | Event Type | Cadence | Day | Title | Descrip. | Agenda | Group | POC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team A | Optional | Weekly | Monday | Co. Q&A | Info. | hyperlink | website | John |
| Team B | Mandatory | Bi-Weekly | Tuesday | Team mtg. | Info. | blank | website | Amy |
| Team C | Mandatory | Weekly | Monday | Mgr. Sync | Info. | hyperlink | blank | Chris |

Tried IF statements with ISBLANK as well as <>"" but I am not sure if I am putting those in the right place.

The formula below is another variation, which works to populate a separate sheet, but it also does NOT skip blanks and is only pulling the first instance found.

=iferror(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($D$3,$C$8,D$7), DataC!$A$1:$M$160,MATCH($A$11,DataC!$A$1:$M$1,0),0),"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try wrapping your working formula within QUERY()

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER($F$2:$M, $B$2:$B=$O$2, $D$2:$D=$Q$2, $E$2:$E=$P$2)),"Select * Where Col1!=''")
```

[image]

Comment: When I add the "QUERY" function, I lose the hyperlinks (because they are embedded).... If they are JUST hyperlinks, it works.

If I do it this way, I'd have to create some kind of separate function that matches the hyperlinks to the appropriate label and then replaces them possibly..... any thoughts on that part?

Comment: Try: =FILTER(FLATTEN(FILTER($F$2:$M, $B$2:$B=$O$2, $D$2:$D=$Q$2, $E$2:$E=$P$2)),FLATTEN(FILTER($F$2:$M, $B$2:$B=$O$2, $D$2:$D=$Q$2, $E$2:$E=$P$2))<>"")